# If a group has exactly 24 elements of order 6, how many subgroups of order 6 does it have?

Tags: group-theory

I have no idea how the two are related. I can figure out that the group should have at least 30 elements because the number has to be more than 24 and divisible by 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** The problem is not well-determined. The group $C_6 \times C_6$ has 24 elements of order 6, and 12 subgroups of order 6. The group $S_3 \times C_3 \times C_3$ also has 24 elements of order 6, but beyond the 12 cyclic subgroups this necessarily gives, it also has the subgroup $S_3 \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$.

The following two hints lead to an answer only under additional assumptions: e.g., $G$ is abelian, or we consider only cyclic subgroups.

Hint 1: How many elements of order 6 are there in a subgroup of order 6?

Hint 2: Can an element of order 6 belong to more than one subgroup of order 6?

Comment: 1) 2 right, <5> and <1>.

Comment: 2) I have no idea.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding how these two hints contribute to solving the problem (leaving aside isomorphisms with $S_3$).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I understand that bit. I am trying to understand how the 2nd hint helps with the problem, say when it is abelian?

Comment: @user2277550, the answer is "no" -- an element of order 6 generates its subgroup of order 6, so it belongs to only one subgroup. That means that there is a bijection between cyclic subgroups of order 6 en pairs of elements of order 6, so that there are half as many cyclic subgroups of order 6 as there are elements of order 6. If $G$ is abelian, then all subgroups of order six are cyclic, as the only other group of order six is $S_3$.